# Colhemos informações para te ajudar(mos) a se preparar

Tags: gramática, infinitivo-pessoal

Qual o correto:

1. Colhemos informações para te ajudar a se preparar
2. Colhemos informações para te ajudarmos a se preparar

Ou ambos são possíveis e é só questão de estilo?

Comment: Tecnicamente, nenhuma, pela mistura de *te* (segunda pessoa) com *se* (terceira pessoa), ao menos que *se* não se refira à mesma pessoa que *te*. Ignorando isso, ambas as frases estão corretas. https://www.todamateria.com.br/infinitivo-pessoal-e-infinitivo-impessoal/.

Comment: Para ser mais formal, o lhe seria melhor. Ou seja: para ajudar a você. Mais o prononimal é desnecessário. Para ajudarnos a lhe preparar, não é a mesma coisa que para lhe ajudar a se preparar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O **infinitivo pessoal**, que é o que está em variação nessas frases é algo longe de regular nos diversos dialetos de português. Ambas as formas são possíveis e os falantes variam muito no seu uso, em termos atuais e até históricos! O português, o galego e o sardo são as únicas línguas que possuem tal flexão no infinitivo.

Comment: O "mos" é presente/pretérito perfeito do indicativo, embora este em jogo a diferença entre uso do infinitivo ou indicativo.

Comment: Não, "-mos" é uma flexão de pessoa-número (neste caso, primeira pessoa do plural) e é usado nesses dois tempos que citou e no infinitivo pessoal, que é o tema da pergunta.

Comment: Pois infinitivo pessoal, não me lembrei disso.

Comment: Eu diria que a forma flexionada tente a enfatizar o agente (no exemplo, "nós"), independente de preferências pessoais.

Answer (score 2):

A [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9501/2764) do Ergative está correta — ambas as frases são aceitáveis — mas o infinitivo impessoal (não flexionado) [é preferível](https://www.normaculta.com.br/concordancia-verbal-com-verbos-no-infinitivo/):

> **Concordância verbal facultativa com infinitivo impessoal ou pessoal**
>
> **Com o mesmo sujeito das duas orações**
>
> Quando o sujeito é o mesmo nas duas orações, é facultativa a escolha do infinitivo pessoal ou impessoal, mesmo que o sujeito esteja oculto. Contudo, nestas situações, há uma maior preferência dos falantes pela forma no singular.
>
> - Viemos para transmitir as palavras do diretor.
> - Viemos para transmitirmos as palavras do diretor.
> - Lá estarão para resolver o problema.
> - Lá estarão para resolverem o problema.